# VBScript .run когда в пути есть пробелы (с переменной)

Tags: windows, vbscript

Добрый день! В `VBScript` все знают, что бы открыть файл через `createObject(WSCript.Shell)` когда в пути к файлу есть пробел, то надо сделать так:

```
Dim prog, path
Set prog = createObject("WSCript.Shell")

prog.run("""C:\Users\Me\Desktop\my file.xls""")
```

Тройные кавычки помогли здесь, но если случай такой:

```
Dim prog, path
Set prog = createObject("WSCript.Shell")
path = Left(wscript.scriptfullname, (Len(wscript.scriptfullname) - Len(wscript.scriptname))) & "my file.xls"
prog.run("cmd.exe" & " " & path) 'Ошибка
```

И вот где здесь ставить двойные кавычки? Я что-то туплю. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кратные кавычки только сбивают с толку. Лучше добавляйте их в явной форме с использованием соответствующей функции. Во-первых, сразу видно, где они, во-вторых, не надо считать кавычки, боясь недоложить или перестараться.

Так - можно, но плохо

```
prog.run("""C:\Users\Me\Desktop\my file.xls""")
```

А так - гораздо нагляднее

```
prog.run(CHR(34) & "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\my file.xls" & CHR(34))
```

Так - ошибка

```
path = Left(wscript.scriptfullname, (Len(wscript.scriptfullname) - Len(wscript.scriptname))) & "my file.xls"
prog.run("cmd.exe" & " " & path)
```

А так - обязано работать

```
    REM Получить имя
path = Left(wscript.scriptfullname, (Len(wscript.scriptfullname) - Len(wscript.scriptname))) & "my file.xls"
    REM Обрамить его кавычками
quoted_path = CHR(34) & path & CHR(34)
    REM И выполнить команду
prog.run("cmd.exe" & " " & quoted_path)
```